# How to add webp support in CK Editor in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

Drupal 9.3.9

Webp images were not loaded into the Media Library. I went to `Media types -> Image -> Edit` and added webp to the `"Allowed file extensions"` field - after that, webp images began to load

Now I noticed that web images are not loaded into CK Editor when editing any page. Writes that "The selected file bg_main_0.webp cannot be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: gif, png, jpg, jpeg."

I went to `Structure -> Content types -> Article -> Manage fields - Edit` and also added webp to the "Allowed file extensions" field - it didn't help

Tell me, please, where to dig?

Comment: Ensure you are editing the image field for the content type you are testing (article?). Also, CKEditor itself has a [client side config which includes an image type filter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html#configuring-allowed-file-types), normally it should allow webp by default but it is worth checking if is actually the case (you might have a [custom config](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/ckeditor/overview#s-custom-configuration) somewhere overriding this).

Comment: Looks like this is the answer  
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3386605  

Update \Drupal\ckeditor5\Controller\CKEditor5ImageController::upload() to add webp as a valid file name extension.  

Update core/modules/ckeditor5/ckeditor5.ckeditor5.yml -> ckeditor5_imageUpload -> ckeditor5 -> config -> image -> upload -> types to add webp as a valid IANA file type.

Answer (score 0):

You should drag and drop separate 'Insert from Media Library' button into CKEditor toolbar.